# the type or namespace could not be found VS2013

Tags: c#, namespaces

I'm begginer programmer. My friend and me are working on one project and he send me his project, but those namespaces could not be found.

Can you please tell me what is wrong?
Here is whole screen shot.

[ScreenShot](http://ctrlv.cz/shots/2015/01/06/rLMO.png)

It says exactly this:

> Error 5   The type or namespace name 'MetaBuilders' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)  C:\Users\example\Desktop\project\COGLAPP-master\NAntiCheat\Forms\FormIRC.cs 9   7   NAntiCheat

or another namespaces, there is a lot of them.

> Error 12  The type or namespace name 'IrcMessageEventArgs' could not be
>   found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly
>   reference?)   C:\Users\example\Desktop\project\COGLAPP-master\NAntiCheat\Forms\FormIRC.cs 77  48  NAntiCheat

Comment: Add the namespace/dll to your references/assembly and/or be sure that you have `namespace MetaBuilders { }` above your code.

Comment: did you reference dll where the namespace MetaBuilders exists ?

Comment: I would suggest reading a good tutorial and keeping a site like this at your disposal until you become more proficient with C# .NET Programming [C# NameSpaces & Tutorial for Beginners](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/csharp/csharp_namespaces.htm)

Comment: I think, that Nu-Get hasn't downloaded the libraries..

Answer (score 0):

Add the `.dll` to your references/assembly folder. In your `Solution explorer`, right click and add reference: find where your `.dll` is saved and add it via **Add Reference**. After adding this, it should solve your issue. You may have quite possibly saved it in your project folder.

Comment: Yes, thank you. Can someone upload me InputManager.dll ? I cannot find it anywhere on internet.

Comment: Okay i finally found it.

Comment: If this helped at all remember to accept an answer.